# How to show JSON in TableLayout?

Tags: android, json, tablelayout

How do I show this in a tablelayout? I want to display a json-file like this:
[image: Image1]

In my code below the network connection is working which parses a image name and a url and displaying this. I just want to know how to add some new attributes in my json-file like item quantity.

and access in my json parsing code and display in layout same like this image.

This is my JSON file

```
{ "worldpopulation":
    [
        {
            "rank":1,
            "name": "Angelina",
            "url": "http://www.bounty4u.com/android/images/angie.jpg"
        },
        {   
            "rank":2,
            "name": "Ashton ",
            "url": "http://www.bounty4u.com/android/images/ashton.jpg"
        },
        {  
            "rank":3,
            "name": "Jackman",
            "url": "http://www.bounty4u.com/android/images/hugh.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my code:

```
public class fifthscreen extends Activity {

HorizontalListView listview;
CategoryListAdapter3 cla;
String DescriptionAPI;

static ArrayList<Long> Category_ID = new ArrayList<Long>();
static ArrayList<String> Category_name = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> Category_image = new ArrayList<String>();


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fifthscreen);


    listview = (HorizontalListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listview2);

      cla = new CategoryListAdapter3(fifthscreen.this);


      DescriptionAPI = Utils.DescriptionAPI;

         //     clearData();
            try {

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

  HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 
   15000);
                HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(DescriptionAPI);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                InputStream atomInputStream = 
       response.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
       InputStreamReader(atomInputStream));

                String line;
                String str = "";
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                    str += line;
                }


                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
                    JSONArray data =  
       json.getJSONArray("worldpopulation");



                   for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = data.getJSONObject(i); 

                    //    JSONObject category = 
               object.getJSONObject("Category");


                            Category_ID.add(Long.parseLong(object.getString("rank")));
                        Category_name.add(object.getString("name"));
                        Category_image.add(object.getString("url"));

                        Log.d("Category name", Category_name.get(i));
                        listview.setAdapter(cla);


                    }


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            //  IOConnect = 1;
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   


  public class CategoryListAdapter3 extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;

public CategoryListAdapter3(Activity act) {
    this.activity = act;
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(act);
}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return fifthscreen.Category_ID.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewitem2, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    holder.txtText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title2);
    holder.imgThumb = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image2);

    holder.txtText.setText(fifthscreen.Category_name.get(position));
//  
 imageLoader.DisplayImage(Utils.AdminPageURL+CategoryList.Category_image.get(position),
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(fifthscreen.Category_image.get(position),
            activity, holder.imgThumb);

    return convertView;
}


 }
```

Comment: just ad new array in my json file quantity items  and access and display in layout how do ido that???

Answer (score 0):

Why you going to use table layout. Same features available as a listview and it is very easy to use so I suggest you to use this features. It provide multiple column facility as tablelayout.

Please see this [link](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2009/02/15/multicolumn-listview-in-android/)

Comment: i dont know how to display json data like this.  please just add some dummy "item"  "quantity" in my json file like this image http://imgur.com/v4WpJdN  and display on screen same like this screen please help me

Comment: im not using String i m getting data form json file. do my litle favour add some nodes or array inmy json file and display them same like this image  http://imgur.com/v4WpJdN   plz

Comment: i dont know this data which is show in image http://imgur.com/v4WpJdN is array ormultiple nodes in json file  i paste my json file above just add some new data there like "item"quantity" access in y json code and display same like this screen http://imgur.com/v4WpJdN

Answer (score 0):

use google gson

**Gson is a Java library that can be used to convert Java Objects into their JSON representation. It can also be used to convert a JSON string to an equivalent Java object. Gson can work with arbitrary Java objects including pre-existing objects that you do not have source-code of.**

its easy to use json_encode() in php

see the link below

[read](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Comment: please reply on my this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990514/how-to-show-json-in-column-my-json-not-display